# unable to navigate from fragment which has a list view to another fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

I have a fragment which contains a list view. Within that fragment I am attempting to  navigate to another fragment as soon as one of the items in the list is clicked but I get an error stating that

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView

this is my code

```
private void setupList(View view) {
      //super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      //setContentView(R.layout.icons_main);

      CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this.getActivity(), itemname, imgid);
      //CustomListAdapter adapter=new CustomListAdapter(this, itemname, imgid);
      list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
      //(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.lv_listview);
      list.setAdapter(adapter);
      list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                 int position, long id) {
            String Slecteditem = itemname[+position];
           // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Slecteditem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Fragment fragment = new SensorInformationChildFragment(); 
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.list, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

         }
      });
   }
```

the error I am getting

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView
    at android.widget.AdapterView.addView(AdapterView.java:452)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1124)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1290)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1677)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:536)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: AdapterView(ListView) doesn't like when you are messing with its children... and you wana replace em with fragment ... just use some outer container ... edit: IMHO it would be better to replace ListView with ListFragment ... then the ListView would be a part of the ListFragment which you wana replace so you would not have such problems ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way and advisable way of communicating between a fragments and their activity does not advise that and actually it hardly work!!

There is something about the fragment you are having!! The id you have passed is of a listview while the best implementation of the fragments in an activity is having a container(Frame layout the prefered one). This will be replaced with another fragment at runtime if you want. But it looks like you want to replace the listview which is like (Adapter View). So my suggestion prepare an activity_main.xml. Then put a Frame_Layout with an id "container" (just a convention). Then prepare your first fragment with a list view and at runtime you will be replacing the content of the container(the Frame layout) with another fragment.

The other thing you need to know is how to call a method in the parent activity from one of its fragments because ANDROID DOCUMENTATION says fragments should not communicate between themselves but ONLY through the parent activity so make sure you follow it here!! [Get all information here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). The information there are for official documentation but for  more information and tutorials you can check
[This tutorial](http://www.truiton.com/2015/12/android-activity-fragment-communication/) or [Another Tutorial.](http://simpledeveloper.com/how-to-communicate-between-fragments-and-activities/)

Comment: @xenolin thank you I work better with tutorials could you please give me a link

Comment: @FlyBYNight I have modified the answer to include The link to necessary tutorials. Remember to accept my answer if it was helpful!!